# Create PHP Array Where Matching Keys have Some Value

Tags: php, arrays

This is the first post from a PHP noob. My question relates to an HTML/PHP form which posts the following three types of data generated by a MySQL query:

ID (always posted via a hidden input field)
Mileage (only some entries may be completed, others might be left blank)
Vehicle Type (always posted via a hidden input field)

This data is all for one of three companies that are selected on the page preceding the data-posting page ie.

**Step One:** Choose company and year. Press submit.

**Step Two:** See results from MySQL query and enter in mileages where necessary. Press submit.

**Step Three:** (that's why I'm here)

I've stuffed this data into what I (probably mistakenly) believe is a multidimensional array called $idmilearray by using the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['mileage'])) {
    $mileagenumber = $_POST['mileage'];
}

if(isset($_POST['idnos'])) {
    $idnumber = $_POST['idnos'];
}

if(isset($_POST['vehicle'])) { 
    $vehicletype = $_POST['vehicle'];
}

$idmilearray = array(
'ids' => $idnumber,
'mileage' => $mileagenumber,
'vtype' => $vehicletype
);


foreach($idmilearray as $inputs) {

$inputs = $idmilearray['ids'];
$inputs = $idmilearray['mileage'];
$inputs = $idmilearray['vtype'];

}
```

If I execute a print_r on the $idmilearray I get the following results:

```
 Array
 (
  [ids] => Array
    (
        [0] => 35
        [1] => 22
        [2] => 32
        [3] => 38
        [4] => 36
        [5] => 39
        [6] => 16
        [7] => 20
        [8] => 48
        [9] => 46
    )

[mileage] => Array
    (
        [0] => 334
        [1] => 56
        [2] => 
        [3] => 43
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => 
        [8] => 11
        [9] => 5
    )

[vtype] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10T
        [1] => 10T
        [2] => 10T
        [3] => Artic
        [4] => 10T
        [5] => Artic
        [6] => Artic
        [7] => 10T
        [8] => Artic
        [9] => 10T
    )
```

What I would like to do is to create another array (the values of which I can use in later SQL queries) but only where the keys contain *something* in [ids][0], [mileage][0] and [vtype][0] and so on and so forth. I'd like to use [mileage] as the 'reference array'.

I've been playing around with array_intersect_key and array_diff_key but I've hit a big and rather a nasty wall. Can anyone help or give some pointers?

Thanks very much for your time.

Regards,

External.

Comment: what is the actual result you want ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. An example would be where keys [0], [1] and [8] (in my example) were returned *with* their values so I can determine the vehicle type and id number for whatever mileage was entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use what you have to insert directly into mysql as follows:

```
foreach ( $idmilearray['mileage'] as $KEY => $VAL ) {
    if ( empty($VAL) ) continue;
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tableName` (id, mileage, vtype) VALUES ('{$idmilearray['ids'][$KEY]}', '$VAL', '{$idmilearray['vtype'][$KEY]}')";
}
```

Or if you really want to merge everything for further processing or whatever reason you can do it like so:

```
$NewArray = [];
foreach ( $idmilearray['mileage'] as $KEY => $VAL ) {
    if ( empty($VAL) ) continue;
    $NewArray[] = array('id' => $idmilearray['ids'][$KEY], 'mileage' => $VAL, 'vtype' => $idmilearray['vtype'][$KEY]);
}
```

Ofcourse there are many other possible ways to do this, but these are the easiest given what you currently have.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. This is what I needed; a push in the right direction. I tried to upvote you all but I don't have the reputation score to change the public vote. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `foreach`, inside your **existing** foreach and fill your new array by checking the old array values with `if (!empty($old_array)) {}`

Example:

```
foreach($idmilearray as $inputs) {
  $inputs = $idmilearray['ids'];
  $inputs = $idmilearray['mileage']; // This is the one you want, right?
  $inputs = $idmilearray['vtype'];
}
```

To do the job you need, it would be something like this:

```
$new_array = []; // Short array syntax (PHP 5.3+)
foreach($idmilearray as $inputs) {
  $inputs = $idmilearray['ids'];

  foreach($idmilearray['mileage'] as $mileage) {
    if (!empty($mileage)) {
      $new_array[] = $mileage;
    }
  }

  $inputs = $idmilearray['vtype'];
}
```

Now you have new array (`$new_array`) filled only with the keys that links to existing values.

I hope it helps you.